# UITabbar Application with different Orientations

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

i've got a iPad TabBarApplication. i subclassed the TabbarController to make the Application react to a orientation change:

@implementation frankenlandTabBarController

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
            );
}


@end
```

the problem now is, that i dont want ALL viewcontrollers of my tabbarapp in this orientations.

overwriting the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method in a single controller does not have any effect.

any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Implementing the mentioned `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method in a specific view controller to prevent rotation works for me though.

Comment: @brutella also in a tabbar application?

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is only called for the top-level view controller. As long as this is the tab bar controller, the other views will not get a chance to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to change the orientation for one view in a tabBar and not for another. If a TabBar is specified then all the subviews (tabs) must have the same orientation appearance. You must set the orientation in each ViewController and in the TabBarController.